# Renaming files randomly with AppleScript isn't working

Tags: applescript, finder

I would like to take a directory's files and rename them by reassigning their existing filenames randomly among the same files.

For example, if a directory had the following three files (name and file size):

```
filenameA   100KB
filenameB   200KB
filenameC   300KB
```

After running the script, it might look like this:

```
filenameB   100KB
filenameC   200KB
filenameA   300KB
```

So there would be 6 [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) for three files, 24 for four files, etc….

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "System Events" to set theFiles to every file of folder "/path/to/my/directory"
    repeat count of theFiles times
        tell application "System Events" to set theFiles to every file of folder "/path/to/my/directory"
        set randint1 to random number from 1 to count of theFiles
        set randint2 to random number from 1 to count of theFiles
        set theName1 to name of item randint1 of theFiles
        set theName2 to name of item randint2 of theFiles
        set name of item randint1 of theFiles to "randomname"
        set name of item randint2 of theFiles to theName1
        set name of item randint1 of theFiles to theName2
    end repeat
end tell
```

Running this code doesn't return any errors, however it doesn't work either.

I hope it's clear what the script is supposed to do.

Comment: The `Finder` and `System Events` return different types of items. Either use only the Finder (specifying colon separated HFS paths) or only System Events. Both can rename files.

Comment: @vadian After replacing Finder with System Events, it still doesn't work

Comment: That's too much (and uncontrolled) random. You should get an error at the lastest when "randomname" is going to be assigned to an item with the same name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After grabbing the initial files and file names, this script randomizes the file names into a separate list. It then temporarily renames each file to prevent name collisions. Finally, it cycles through each file and  changes its file name to a random one and removes that name from the pool of eligible names.

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- choose folder, list its files and file names
    set baseFol to choose folder
    set origFiles to files of baseFol as alias list -- list of files
    set origNames to name of files of baseFol as alias list -- list of file names

-- create list of randomized names
set randNames to {}
set cc to 0
repeat count of origNames times -- pool of file names
    set cc to cc + 1 -- increment counter to one above current list length
    repeat until (count of randNames) is cc
        set somName to some item of origNames
        if randNames does not contain somName then
            set end of randNames to somName -- increment list length to match counter
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat

-- temporarily rename files to avoid name collisions
repeat with tmpName in origFiles
    set name of tmpName to "g" & space & name of tmpName
end repeat
set tmpFiles to files of baseFol as alias list -- all g-files list

-- rename each file to final name
repeat with finNames in tmpFiles
    set name of finNames to (item 1 of randNames) -- use random name
    set randNames to rest of randNames -- remove used name from name pool
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Could you please rename some of the variables as a Users who might have the same question does not know what `cc`, `si`, `rNomBaseFol`, etc. could mean.

Comment: Glad it helped. The first two don't really mean anything but 'si' is for 'some item' and 'cc' is just a counter. The third one is for 'random name base folder'. I'll see if I can come up with something meaningful.

Comment: The intent of **AppleScript** is to be English like and very human readable, with one aspect of it having the names of the variables easily impart what they are and represent, and not be so cryptic as the examples in this answer. The variable naming coding style in this answer, compared to the other answer, is cryptic and much harder to read and follow throughout the code! Please stop being so cryptic in the variable naming coding style as it's a disservice to the intent of the language and it probably makes it quite difficult for most of the people asking/reading to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't pretty but this following AppleScript code should accomplish, what I believe you are looking to achieve.

```
activate
set containingFolder to (choose folder) as text

tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of alias containingFolder as alias list
end tell

set theNumber to 0

set numberList to {}
set randomNumbersList to {}

repeat (count of theFiles) times
    set theNumber to theNumber + 1
    set end of numberList to theNumber
end repeat

repeat with thisNumber in numberList
    set thisNumber to some item of numberList
    if thisNumber is not in randomNumbersList then
        set end of randomNumbersList to thisNumber
    else
        repeat while randomNumbersList contains thisNumber
            set thisNumber to some item of numberList
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        set end of randomNumbersList to thisNumber
    end if
end repeat

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theFiles
        set thisItem to item i of theFiles
        set name of thisItem to "randomname " & ¬
            (item i of randomNumbersList as text) & "." & name extension of thisItem
    end repeat
end tell
```